# oauth access token validation google

Tags: oauth, access-token, validating

How can we validate the Oauth access token being used for accessing a resource ?Here is the scenario i am facing .I am storing the long-lived access token for accessing a resource.Now it suddenly started failing for that access token and i could not find any error as to why this token failed.When i regenerated the token it started working again. So to say in short can i validate the OAuth Access token before using it?If so how?
I have tried steps given at 
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#validatingtoken .But that is faling and giving 
{
 "error": "invalid_token",
 "error_description": "Bad Request"
} even in case of vaid tokens.

Comment: There is an expire time associated with the token. check that